# Display updates for Maven transitive dependencies

Tags: maven

Say I have a POM which declares a handful of `dependencies` in some scope (`test` in my case but should not matter). These in turn pull in a rather larger number of transitive dependencies. I have the `requireUpperBoundDeps` Enforcer rule active to ensure that every such transitive dependency is at the newest version required by something “above” it.

My goal is to ensure that every dependency in this tree is at the latest available version (which will sometimes be newer than any stated dependency requirement), while keeping the POM as short as feasible. How can I do this?

`mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` shows only updates available to immediate dependencies, it seems. I recall that there is an Enforcer rule available to force all dependencies to be explicit, which would solve the issue but at the cost of making the POM much longer—redundantly specifying every transitive dependency, even when it would have been determined to be the currently latest version anyway.

Is there a variant of `display-dependency-updates` that also processes transitive dependencies?

Comment: I had the same idea : I submitted an issue [there](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/267)